# blur background image with sharp edge and clean same image on it.

Tags: css, html

This is what I am trying to do...

[image]

```
.detail_image{ 
   background:url("../images/hero-images.jpg") no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position:center;
   padding: 0 0 30%;
   position: relative;
   height:698px;
}
.detail_overlay{
   background:url("../images/overlay-detail.png");
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
   -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
.detail_img{
   height: 100%;
   margin-left: 165px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

and what is happening is the entire div got blurred with image on it and edges are blurred too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blur` CSS filter, like you see for yourself, blurs everything including the image border. To have crisp borders while maintaining the blurred content you will need a parent element to house it.

Consider the following code:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blurred-image {
    filter: blur(20px);
}

<div class="container">
    <img class="blurred-image" src="path/to/image">
</div>
```

This would act as a clipping mask to the contained `.blurred-image` and as long as the sizes match will guarantee crisp borders and blurred inner content.

Comment: what's the difference from my answer below? :)

Comment: Your explanation is vague and lacks example code. Also, as an abstract proof of concept, there is no need for the user to provide code snippets. The method is clear and straightforward.

Comment: While I'm sure Rahul might find your fiddle useful, it arrives late and it's mainly solving a current issue rather than explaining a concept. Teach a man to fish...
Either way, not a competition and thank you for participating in the community.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you for addressing the problem. this is working as it supposed to be.. only thing is the blurry edges of the background image.. is it possible to make it sharp?

Answer (score 1):

create parent DIV container for the DIV, which is getting blurred, with the same dimensions and overflow hidden. So it will create the clipping mask for your blurred div.

If you'll provide some code snippets on `JSFiddle`, I may help you out with the code.

Comment: @RahulGupta, the code and naming was a bit messy in your example, but I tried to clean it up a bit, and to reproduce what you wanted on the screenshot in the original question: https://jsfiddle.net/ug26errq/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent"><div class="backgroundImg"></div><div class="frontImg"></div></div>
```

Zoom your background image to 105% and clip the borders to have a sharpen edges or put the same image at back of the blurred image.

Provide some sample Fiddle, that would be helpful.